# Can I write a function that behaves like REGEXP_LIKE, ie the result type of which behaves as a boolean?

Tags: oracle

In Oracle, usually, SQL functions that should return true/false return 1/0 because the `BOOLEAN` data type only exists in PL/SQL blocks.

For example with Oracle Text, you must not forget the *`> 0`* in `SELECT * FROM bartbl WHERE CONTAINS(foocol, 'sometext') > 0`. Otherwise you get `ORA-00920` invalid relational operator.

However, it seems that `REGEXP_LIKE` behaves like a true boolean: you can do `SELECT * FROM bartbl WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(foocol, 'sometext')` and it works.

So I would like to know why this is the case and if there is a possibility for me to write some functions like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle's built in functions are special, you can't write one like this yourself.  I don't know why though

Answer (score 1):

Once upon a time, there was no boolean requirement in ANSI SQL (not sure if that requirement exists in latest standards?), and Oracle tends to do their own thing sometimes ;)   But, personally I don't see the issue in using Y/N or 1/0.

Anyway, REGEXP_LIKE is really a type of filter (can reduce the number of rows returned), not the same as a typical function (which will return a value (or null) for each row it processes).  But good thing is that if you really want to mimic the filter functionality, you can use REGEXP_LIKE with your own function.  For example:

```
create or replace function is_big_number(i_num in number)
return varchar2
as

begin
  if (i_num >= 1000000) then
    return 'Y';
  end if;
  return 'N';
end;

with x as (
  select 50000 as num from dual
  union all
  select 1000000 as num from dual
  union all
  select 3 as num from dual
)
select num, is_big_number(num)
from x
-- this is a filter, not a typical "function"
where
regexp_like(is_big_number(num), 'Y');
```

Output:

```
NUM IS_BIG_NUMBER(NUM)
1000000 "Y"
```

Hope that helps.